# Python unitttest discover importing non-modules

Tags: python, unit-testing

I have a Python package organized roughly as such:

```
pkg
--subpkg1
  --foo.py
  --bar.py
--subpkg2
  --baz.py
  --buz.py
```

When I run unittest discover passing in pkg as the start location, it imports the tests I have put in those packages, but throws import errors saying things like "failed to import pkg.subpkg2..idea" or "failed to import pkg.subpkg2." Is there anyway to run discover from a root without having it fail when it discovers folders that are not Python modules? Would be nice if I didn't have to specify each individual test.

Comment: Do you have non unittest objects that are called test_* ?

Comment: nope, that doesn't seem to be the problem

Comment: I suggest you show at least one code file, one test file, the command line you run, and the error you see. When I try to reproduce the problem, unittest doesn't find the tests unless the folder has an `__init__.py` file in it. Creating a gist so people can see a complete example would be great.